# How do i get for-of loop working in google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-tag-manager

I would like to run the following script:

```
<script>

    var pixels = document.body.querySelectorAll(':scope > script[id^="tidio"]');
    for (p of pixels) { document.body.removeChild(p); }

</script>
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error at line 4, character 5: This language feature is only supported
> for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: for-of loop.

Suggestions?

Comment: You could either enable ECMASCIRPT6 mode in GTM as mentioned in the  error message or use a plain `for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) { /* pixels[i] is the pixel */}`. Be aware that querySelectorAll might return `null` on no match instead of the empty Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error at line 4, character 5: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: for-of loop.

this mean that `for..of` is not supported by your browser, However you still can use `forEach` method:

```js
let pixels = document.querySelectorAll("div#root > div")
pixels.forEach(e => e.parentElement.removeChild(e))
```

```html
<div id="root" style="height:20vh;background-color:green">
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
<div> 4 </div>
<div> 5 </div>
<div>
```